# Change size of columns of UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

My question is how to change the size of columns in a UIPickerView object. I've tried set widthForComponent but this does not make the touch points wider. for example, in the UIDatePicker the day and month columns are wider than the other components. how can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the column widths for a `UIDatePicker`. For a `UIPickerView`, you need to implement the `pickerView:widthForComponent:` delegate method.

Comment: I went back and played with pickerView:widthForComponent: and I achieved what I was looking for! I had tried it before but gave up too early. I also found it helpful to use (UIView *)pickerView: method to set size and alignment of columns to get the data in the correct place. Thanks!